# Funçao para marcar/desmarcar checkbox, jquery

Tags: jquery

Como posso fazer para marcar/desmarcar checkbox em jQuery ao clicar num botao e ao mesmo tempo dar um alert relatando se foi marcada ou desmarcada..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Desta forma:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){

    if($( '#mycheckbox' ).prop( "checked" ) == true){
           alert('desmarcado')
           $( '#mycheckbox' ).prop( "checked" , false)
    } else {
         alert('marcado')
         $( '#mycheckbox' ).prop( "checked" , true)
    }
})
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando no aqui
http://jsfiddle.net/ceLnm2eb/1/

Comment: me ajudou muito, obrigado pela postagem

Answer (score 6):

HTML:

```
<ul class="chk-container">
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="selecctall"/> Selecionar todos</li>
    <li><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="item1">Item #01</li>
    <li><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="item2">Item #02</li>
    <li><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="item3">Item #03</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selecctall').click(function(event) {
        if(this.checked) {
            $('.checkbox1').each(function() {
                this.checked = true;               
            });
        }else{
            $('.checkbox1').each(function() {
                this.checked = false;        
            });         
        }
    });

});
```