# Como marcar checkbox?

Tags: javascript

Eu queria saber qual comando Javascript posso executar no site 
para marcar a caixa da imagem sem clicar nela.

É necessário saber sobre o html da caixa?

Antes:

[image]

Depois

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: pegue  o id do checkbox, e marque a propriedade checked como true.

Comment: exemplo com jquery: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49673/fun%C3%A7ao-para-marcar-desmarcar-checkbox-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você se refere a um checkbox, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

HTML exemplo:

```
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox" value="Bike">Checkbox<br>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myCheckbox = document.getElementById('my_checkbox');
myCheckbox.checked = true;
```

Acessando dentro de um iframe:

```
var myFrame = document.getElementById('my_frame');
var myCheckbox = myFrame.contentDocument.getElementById('my_checkbox');
myCheckbox.checked = true;
```

Comment: e si esta caixa estiver dentro de um frame ?

Comment: Daria para fazer assim:

document.getElementById( "my_frame" ).contentDocument.getElementById('my_checkbox').checked = true;